# Error formatting a string: Index (zero based) must be greater than or equal to zero and less than the size of the argument list.. with here string

Tags: powershell

I am using Powershell here-strings to format a HTML body but get the error below:

```
Error formatting a string: Index (zero based) must be greater than or equal to zero and less than the size of the argument list..
```

The code is below:

```psh
$my_html = @"
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<p>You have been invited to the following SharePoint site:</p><a href={0}>{1}</a>
<p>If you are not sure what your username is, please find it at</p>' + '<a href="https://outside.arup.com/default.aspx">here</a>
<p>Your username is {3}</p><p>Your password is: {4}</p>
<p>Please note that for any support queries, please contact your Arup site owner or Global IT (Applications).</p>
</body>
</html>
"@ -f $url, $siteTitle, $username, $password
```

All of the parameters are initialized and just standard strings. What am I missing?

Thanks

Comment: Actually just noticed my mistake, the parameter placeholders should be 0, 1,2,3 !

Comment: Please provide a self-answer or delete the question if this is just a typo :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you're passing in 4 arguments on the right-hand side of the `-f` PowerShell operator. In your source string, you've got placeholders for `{0}` `{1}` `{3}` and `{4}`. You would need to change `{3}` to `{2}` and change `{4}` to `{3}`.

Answer (score 2):

You can use variables directly into the string block:

```
       $my_html = @"
        <html>
        <head></head>
        <body>
        <p>You have been invited to the following SharePoint site:</p><a href=$url>$siteTitle</a>
        <p>If you are not sure what your username is, please find it at</p>' + '<a href="https://outside.arup.com/default.aspx">here</a>
        <p>Your username is $username</p><p>Your password is: $password</p>
        <p>Please note that for any support queries, please contact your Arup site owner or Global IT (Applications).</p>
        </body>
        </html>
"@
```

Answer (score 1):

Another case might happen:

```
$list = New-Object 'System.Collections.Generic.List[string]'
$list.Add("{0} vs {1}" -f 123,456)  # Same error, 456 would be taken as Add's 2nd argument

$list.Add(("{0} vs {1}" -f 123,456))  # okay
$list.Add("{0} vs {1}" -f @(123,456)) # okay
```